# Kubernetes Pod for one time initial task

Tags: kubernetes

Before I start all the services I need a pod that would do some initialization. But I dont want this pod to be running after the init is done and also all the other pods/services should start after this init is done. I am aware of init containers in a pod, but I dont think that would solve this issue, as I want the pod to exit after initialization.

Comment: Why do you want this Pod to be killed after execution? The [init Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use) seems to be exatly what you need ensuring your operational pod's container will execute only after initialization.

Comment: can you specify what exactly is the task you are looking to accomplish this way

Answer (score 4):

You are recommended to let Kubernetes handle pods automatically instead of manual management by yourself, when you can. Consider [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) for run-once tasks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: myjob
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: 
          image:
```

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f job.yml
```

Kubernetes will create a pod to run that job. The pod will complete as soon as the job exits. Note that the completed job and its pod will be released from consuming resources but not removed completely, to give you a chance to examine its status and log. Deleting the job will remove the pod completely.

Jobs can do advanced things like restarting on failure with exponential backoff, running tasks in parallelism, and limiting the time it runs.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on the Init task, but the init container is the best option you have (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

Kubernetes will create the initContainer before the other container, and when it accomplished it's task, it will exit.

Make the InitContainer exit gracefully (with a code 0) so that k8s will understand that the container completed the task it was meant to do and do no try to restart it.

You init task will be done, and the container will no longer exist

Answer (score 0):

You can try attaching handlers to Container lifecycle events. Kubernetes supports the postStart and preStop events. Kubernetes sends the postStart event immediately after a Container is started, and it sends the preStop event immediately before the Container is terminated.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/