# How to run a container only once that completes after ~10 minutes of execution via a deployment in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, containers

I have just started with Kubernetes.
I need to run a Deployment in Kubernetes with a container that competes for execution after ~10-15 minutes.
When I tried, "restart Policy=Never" doesn't hold true with Deployments.
Reason for opting for Deployment is to use Replicas.

Please provide your inputs on how I can achieve multiple replicas of my Deployment with the container that completes execution and not keep running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes Pod for one time initial task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62589553/kubernetes-pod-for-one-time-initial-task)

Answer (score 2):

You can run a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) as below where the container runs a `sleep` command for `15m`. After 15 minutes the container will exit and pod will be terminated.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - sleep 15m
        image: bash:5.1.0
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: The pod keeps restarting after successful completion. Is there a way I can have this Pod run only once and exit through deployment. 
~
'''
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-dep-test1
  labels:
    app: app-dep-test1
spec:
        #replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-dep-test1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-container
        image: <ECR Repo>
        command: <Run-time parameter's>
        #restartPolicy: "Never"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-dep-test1
'''

Comment: No..you should use `Job` instead of `Deployment`

Comment: Looks like OP wants to run multiple replicas, but how would each replica split the workload between them?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530946/what-is-the-difference-between-always-and-on-failure-for-kubernetes-restart-poli explains meaning of "Never" explicitly than https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy